# Should we prefer Composition over Inheritance when we can only use default constructor

Tags: java, oop, software-design, composition

I know the advantages of Composition over Inheritance but in some situation instances of the class are being created by framework using default constructor and we can not define constructor with parameter nor we can set attribute of the object using setter methods. To make this situation clear consider following example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... str){
        TargetFramework.component(Child.class);
    }
}
```

Here the `TargetFramework` get a `class` and it will create instance of that class behind the scene using default Constructor.

Imagine I want to implement `FramewrokInterface` as below:

```
public interface FrameworkInterface {

    void setup();

    void doAction(Record record);

    void doAnotherAction(Record record, boolean isValid);
}
```

Now I can implement this interface in two ways considering Inheritance and Composition:

**Approach 1:** (Mixing and Matching Composition and Inheritance)

```
public abstract class Parent implements FrameworkInterface {

    RecordValidator recordValidator;

    @Override
    public abstract void setup();

    @Override
    public void doAction(Record record){
        boolean isValid = recordValidator.validate(record);
        doAnotherAction(record, isValid);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void doAnotherAction(Record record, boolean isValid){

    }
}
```

In this Implementation I decided to use composition and I've defined a `RecordValidator` as bellow:

```
public interface RecordValidator {
    boolean validate(Record record);
}
```

The problem here is that I can't set `RecordValidator` in `Parent` class when creating instance of this class because instances of this class are created by framework using default constructor but I can create this instance in setup method in child Class which extends parent class as below:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        recordValidator = new DefaultRecordValidator();
    }
}
```

The setup method of the `FramworkInterface` will be called just after instance created by default Constructor so we can use it to initialize our `RecordValidator` attribute; This is kind of Mixing and Matching Composition and Inheritance together to me because I'm using Composition with Inheritance together. However this approach has its own advantages because I've separated the Concern of validation of record from the Parent class Concerns.

**Approach 2:** (Just Inheritance)

In this approach I've implemented the FrameworkInterface in the following way:

```
public abstract class Parent1 implements FrameworkInterface {

    @Override
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doAction(Record record) {
        boolean isValid = validate(record);
        doAnotherAction(record, isValid);
    }

    @Override
    public void doAnotherAction(Record record, boolean isValid) {

    }

    protected abstract boolean validate(Record record);
}
```

This way instead of using composition and defining `RecordValidator` I've defined abstract `validate` method in my `Parent1` class so that Child class can use it to implement validation behaviour, so the `Child` class can be implemented as follow:

```
public class Child extends Parent1 {

    @Override
    protected boolean validate(Record record) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My question is:

Which approach is better for this situation and what are the pros and cons of them?

Comment: Is your intend to talk purely about java or did you tag the question with `java` because the code samples are in Java?

Comment: Probably because he's reading something (or watching tutorials) about programming in Java and found the `Composition vs. Inheritance` topic questionable. I think you should tag OOP, Software-Design.

Comment: @Turing85  I described a situation that could happen in java and my code examples are in java, I do't know whether it could happen in other languages or not. It is better to explain your answer considering java languages, However I would appreciate the answer that cover the situation even if it is not based on java language.

Comment: @tashkhisi your question is a bit broad, which will lead to different opinion-based answers. I'm sure you can find a lot of great articles on the net, regarding this question. Update: If you're concerned about Dependency Injection, then the target Framework will most likely enable you to invoke any constructor you wish.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I know there are a lot of articles out there about `Composition vs. Inheritance` but it is an special case which happen in some situation when instances of the class are created by Framework. I could not find answer for this special case, I've thought a lot about this situation but I could not came to conclusion which approach is preferable.

Comment: What framework are you using so that it doesn't enable you to invoke any custom constructor (either with or without a parameter)?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Thanks for your time, Specific framework that I'm using is`Hadoop MapReduce`, I did not mention it here and  provided my own samples because it make it easier for other developers to answer this question. You can see an example of `MapReduce` in the following link https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html. In line 45 of code we have `conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);` we pass `Map.class` to the framework and it will create instance of that using default `Constructor`.

Comment: It's better to mention the exact framework, because distributed nature of Hadoop means cannot simply add features like other answer suggests. In this case, I suggest composition is a better fit, especially because you can then reuse the valdation for different mapper classes. Or if you have the option, maybe consider move up to Apache Spark instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Which approach is better for this situation and what are the pros and cons of them?

I would argue that both of them are suboptimal to a degree where I would look for other solutions.

Looking at the sample code, there is, for example, no possibility to mock the dependencies of `Child1` in both situations. You could introduce mock capabilities by implementing setters or special constructors that are only used for testing. The core problem I have with this setup, however, is that you bow to the framework.

I would recommend exploring other possibilities, e.g. do the necessary dependency injection manually, then "register" a finished bean with the framework. This is what Uncle Bob means when he talks about [keeping the framework at arm's length](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/11/FrameworkBound.html).

If we start talking about Java in particular and the framework does not allow any other solution to, e.g., create beans beforehand and registering them with the framework, I would contact the framework maintainers and ask to implement [CDI support](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/partcdi.html#GJBNR) since this is a standardized way to handle Depencency Injection.

Looking at your example, you take two different approaches, i.e. you redefine the capabilites of `Parent`. Just as you did with `Parent` in the inheritance example, you could define `abstract boolean validate();` in `Parent`, delegating the implementation to `Child`. I would even go a step further and define

```
public interface class Parent extends FrameworkInterface, RecordValidator {
    ...
}
```

(all methods in `Parent` are either abstract or can be seen as defaults, the field can be removed). Thus, each class implementing this interface implements the methods as it sees fit.